# I need an alternative solution using plot function

Tags: matlab

How to do the same but without `contour` and `meshgrid` functions? I need an alternative code using `plot` function.

```
[x,y]=meshgrid(linspace(-3,3,1000));
contour(x,y,x.^2 + y.^2-2.*x,'LevelList',0,'LineColor','r','LineWidth',2);
hold on
contour(x,y,x.^2 - y.^2-y,'LevelList',0,'LineColor','b','LineWidth',2);
```

Comment: Why can't you use `meshgrid` and `contour`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is create the matrices `x` and `y` "by hand", create a logical image that represents the sign of your function and use `bwboundaries` to extract the line of "sign changes":

```
t=linspace(-3,3,100);            % set up matrices
o = ones(size(t));          
x = o'*t;
y = x';
image = x.^2 + y.^2-2.*x > 0;    % generate image
BW = bwboundaries(image);        % extract paths from image
hold on
for k=1:numel(BW);
    path = BW{k};
    x = t(path(:,1));
    y = t(path(:,2));
    plot(x,y);                   % plot paths
end
```